# Redis Server Refuses All Connections Via Unix Socket

Tags: ubuntu, redis

I am running Ubuntu server 20.04 LAMP, with Redis 5.0.7.

**Problem:**
When a unix socket has been configured with `port 0` Redis refuses all connections.

basic `/etc/redis/redis.conf`:

```
# create a unix domain socket to listen on
unixsocket /var/run/redis/redis.sock
# set permissions for the socket
unixsocketperm 775
bind 127.0.0.1
daemonize yes
stop-writes-on-bgsave-error no
rdbcompression yes
# maximum memory allowed for redis
maxmemory 50M
# how redis will evice old objects - least recently used
maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
# tells redis to ignore TCP ports
port 0 
#creates pidfile
pidfile /run/redis/redis-server.pid
```

Socket:

```
# ls -lh /var/run/redis
total 4.0K
-rw-rw---- 1 redis redis 5 Jul 30 18:23 redis-server.pid
srwxrwxr-x 1 redis redis 0 Jul 30 18:23 redis.sock
```

Listening Port:

```
# ps aux | grep redis
redis       4912  0.1  0.0  50192  3972 ?        Ssl  18:23   0:01 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:0
root        6395  0.0  0.0   6432   592 pts/1    S+   18:36   0:00 grep --color=auto redis
```

Connections Refused:

```
# redis-cli
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused
not connected> quit
```

and

```
# redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 0 
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:0: Connection refused
```

Firewall completely disabled.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the result of `netstat -anp|grep LISTEN` executed as root?

Comment: Only redis related it `unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     85256    4912/redis-server 1  /var/run/redis/redis.sock`

Comment: So redis do not listen on TCP port. How do you expect to connect? Try `redis-cli -s /var/run/redis/redis.sock`

Comment: Thanks for the tip... I was connecting incorrectly tcp / socket.. Additionally my user trying to connect doesn't have sufficient permissions, whereas root does.   This helped a lot a full solution from here should be easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From comments I see `redis` do not listen to TCP port but only use socket. In such case the connection should be done with command

```
redis-cli -s /var/run/redis/redis.sock
```

The line

```
redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 0
```

connect to IP and port. And you can't use port `0`, AFAIK it's reserverd

Comment: appreciate the helping hand... back on track.. :-)